# How do I force a result from a non-present JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I have local HTML files that use some (but not all) of several JS scripts, how can I bypass scripts that are not present?  My example is using a validation script to check others for version currency.

**HTML**

```html
<script src="validation.js"></script>
<script src="scriptA.js"></script>
```

**scriptA.js**

```js
    const A_VERSION = 3.0;

    function A_GetVersion() {

        "use strict";

        return A_VERSION;

        ...

    }
```

**validation.js**

```
   function main_GetVersions() {

        var AVersion = "";

        try {

            AVersion = A_GetVersion();

        } catch {

            AVersion = "not available";

        }

        alert(AVersion);

        ...

    }
```

---

If scriptA.js is present in the HTML, validation.js an alert displays.

If scriptA.js is absent from the HTML, there is no alert.  I want to see "not available" as an alert.

Comment: what do you see in the browser console?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting)

Comment: How are you calling `main_GetVersions()`? Since scriptA.js is included after validation.js, if `main_GetVersions()` is called before scriptA.js is loaded, you'll get a different answer than if it called after scriptA.js is loaded. Also, is there anything with `A_GetVersion()` that you're not showing? Like it's the result of an HTTP call?

Comment: When I run this in the browser console I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: A_GetVersion is not defined"

Comment: Thanks HereticMonkey.  I'll refer to that for my next post.

Comment: The script is run from <body onload="main_GetVersions();">  The result depends on whether or not scriptA.js is included in the <head> section of the page.

Comment: Is `A_GetVersion` only called inside the `try` block? If yes, you should not get the `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Comment: Yes, @ahendwh2, that function is only called inside the `try` block.  I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VieleFragen/gzcamt31/4/) which shows what I want, but doesn't work the same as in my browser.  I simplified the JavaScript and HTML by putting all of the JavaScript in the same window.  If the function name on line 2 is **A_GetVersion**, the alert shows "3".  If the function name on line 2 is changed to **xA_GetVersion** the alert shows "not available".  My original post describes what still happens when not using the JSFiddle.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some changes to my actual scripts last night (not the test examples) alerts are behaving as I expect.  My issue was probably due to duplicate variable declarations in both of my actual scripts. In VBA (my background), the scope can be global (anywhere in the database), module (any function in that module), or local (that function). I haven't used JS for a while and now realize that I can't have the same variable name in two different script files (global vs. "module")